# How to assign value to class instance members using the instance name in a select method

Tags: c#, linq

I have this method:

```
    public DemographicData GetDemographicByZipCode(string zipcode)
    {
        DemographicData demoData = new DemographicData();

        using(var context = new DataContext())
        {
            var result = from item in context.Demographic
                         where item.ZipCode == zipcode
                         select item;

            foreach (var data in result)
            {
                demoData.City = data.City;
                demoData.State = data.State;
                demoData.Zip = data.ZipCode;
            }
        }

        return demoData;
    }
```

I am attempting to write the method without the loop as indicated below but as apparent, it will not work because I cannot use an assignment operator within the expression tree.

```
    public DemographicData GetDemographicByZipCode(string zipcode)
    {
        DemographicData demoData = null;
        // Instantiate to new instance in the select method.
        // I need to use this instance demoData

        using(var context = new DataContext())
        {
            var result = from item in context.Demographic
                         where item.ZipCode == zipcode

                         select new DemographicData()
                         {
                             //assign data to instance member here.
                         };
        }

        return demoData;
    }
```

Comment: The way you assign `demoData` doesn't make any sense. You have a signle instance in a loop and you're assigning it over and over? It's just gonna take the last values in the loop.

Comment: How many `demoData` objects do you need? Do you need just one or multiple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. But if your goal is for `demoData` to represent a single result from your query, then you can do something like this:

```
public DemographicData GetDemographicByZipCode(string zipcode)
{
    DemographicData demoData = null;

    using(var context = new DataContext())
    {
        demoData = (from item in context.Demographic
                   where item.ZipCode == zipcode
                   select new DemographicData()
                   {
                       Zip = item.ZipCode,
                       City = item.City,
                       State = item.State
                   }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    //Do other stuff to demoData here, if needed

    return demoData;
}
```

That uses `FirstOrDefault` to get the first one in the list (or null if there are none). In the loop in your example, you're just overwriting the values, so I assume you are only expecting one result.

*Update:* If you are expecting more than one result, then return `IEnumerable<DemographicData>`, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<DemographicData> GetDemographicByZipCode(string zipcode)
{
    List<DemographicData> demoData = null;

    using(var context = new DataContext())
    {
        demoData = (from item in context.Demographic
                   where item.ZipCode == zipcode
                   select new DemographicData()
                   {
                       Zip = item.ZipCode,
                       City = item.City,
                       State = item.State
                   }).ToList();
    }

    //Do other stuff to demoData here, if needed

    return demoData;
}
```

Use `List<DemographicData>` and `ToList()` inside the method to force it to actually perform the query there. If you don't use `ToList()`, it will perform the query when the list is first accessed, which will be outside of the `using`, when your context is disposed. It might also complain about multiple enumerations, depending on your code.

Comment: I need to use this demoData instance.

Comment: Why? What are you doing before the query that you cannot do after? (I updated my answer to make it clear that you can do other stuff to `demoData` after the query)

Comment: I see where you are going but there are multiple results returned so FirstOrDefault will only return a single resultset.

Comment: Right, but your code only returns one resultset. You're overwriting the same value each time through the loop. `demoData` is a single object, not a list. So what are you hoping to return?

Comment: Okay, I get it, makes sense, the loop was an error on my part. If I need to return multiple values then I will simply use an enumerable of the instance, in this case for multiple resultsets. Your suggestion is going to work.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can return a list of all the results.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  var result = from item in context.Demographic
                     where item.ZipCode == zipcode
                     select item;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
City = item.City,
State = item.State,
Zip = item.ZipCode
```

What is still wrong with your code is that you are returning single `DemographicData` object whereas result will be collection of `DemographicData` objects even if there is only one that fulfills the condition `tem.ZipCode == zipcode`.

If you are expecting only exactly one instance of   `DemographicData` do it this way

```
var result = (from item in context.Demographic
                     .
                     (your query here)
                     .
                 ).Single();
```

If you are expecting one or zero then replace `Single()` with `FirstOrDefault()`. If you are expecting a collection then the return type of that method should be `IEnumerable<DemographicData>` or `IQueryable<DemographicData>` or any other that suits you best. If you need list/ array then replace `Single()` with `ToList()`/`ToArray()`.